# kubernete service is blocked/loading with minikube in mac

Tags: macos, docker, kubernetes

i've been checking this same config with a team-mate and he can access to the service via browser with his macintosh/laptop.

```
kubectl get services --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE   NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
default     kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          7d23h
default     posts-depl   LoadBalancer   10.100.86.132   <pending>     4000:31578/TCP   102m
default     posts-srv    NodePort       10.101.115.21   <none>        4000:31237/TCP   26h
```

This is my service file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: posts-srv
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: posts
  ports:
    - name: posts
      protocol: TCP
      port: 4000
      targetPort: 4000
```

This is the deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: posts-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: posts
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: posts
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: posts
          image: username/posts:latest
          ports:
          - containerPort: 4000
            name: app
```

Pod:

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
posts-depl-5489b46f-2sprs   1/1     Running   0          25h
```

service info:

```
kubectl describe service posts
Name:                     posts-depl
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=posts
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.100.86.132
Port:                     <unset>  4000/TCP
TargetPort:               4000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31578/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.3:4000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>

Name:                     posts-srv
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"posts-srv","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"posts...
Selector:                 app=posts
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.101.115.21
Port:                     posts  4000/TCP
TargetPort:               4000/TCP
NodePort:                 posts  31237/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.3:4000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

i know, i can access to the node/container with
`kubectl port-forward posts-depl-5489b46f-2sprs 50000:4000` and i-m receiving the right response from nodejs server, but i want to access via the service.

Also, i've been trying to access via load balancer:
`kubectl expose deployment posts-depl --type=LoadBalancer --port=4000`

i can not access to the nodejs response neither with the load-balancer nor with the node-port
Somehow my macintosh is blocking the request from the browser:

url:

```
minikube service posts-srv --url
  Starting tunnel for service posts-srv.
|-----------|-----------|-------------|------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |   NAME    | TARGET PORT |          URL           |
|-----------|-----------|-------------|------------------------|
| default   | posts-srv |             | http://127.0.0.1:54224 |
|-----------|-----------|-------------|------------------------|
http://127.0.0.1:54224
❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on darwin, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```

as i said before, a team-mate of mine can access well to the nodejs response with his mac. Somehow my macintosh is blocking the info inside of kubernet cluster.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: why your LoadBalancer state of EXTERNAL-IP is still pending?

Comment: i added load-balancer to check if the problem only was with the node-port, but the problem is happening with load-balancer too. So, i don't think the problem is with load-balancer. The problem started with the node-port. I just added the load-balancer to confirm it! Thanks!

Comment: Was there any guide you followed in order to make it work? Also, are there any kind of firewall that could block the traffic?